# To whom/which school of thought Mises is responding when affirming that human impulses can be controlled?

Tags: liberalism

Ludwig von Mises makes the affirmation that human instincts and impulses can be exerted control over:

> What distinguishes man from beasts is precisely that he adjusts his behavior deliberatively. Man is the being that has inhibitions, that can master his impulses and desires, that has the power to suppress instinctive desires and impulses.

[Chapter 1](https://oll.libertyfund.org/page/mises-on-human-action) of Mises, *Human Action: A Treatise on Economics*, in 4 vols., ed. Bettina Bien Greaves (Indianapolis: Liberty Fund, 2007). Vol. 1.

To whom/which school of thought Mises is responding here, in refutation?

Comment: Why would he be refuting anyone? The idea humans have an animal nature but also a uniquely human ability to control that goes back at least to Aristotle's tripartite picture of the soul. Looking at the text it seems like he's asserting that our animal impulses don't invalidate our capacities to be beings of reason

Comment: He is refuting conductism